# Python Selenium select all the href from a main <div>

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am currently trying to get the `href` out of the following web page structure:

```
<div style="something> # THIS IS THE MAIN DIV I CAN GET
    <div class="aegieogji"> # First ROW sub-div under the main div
        <div class="aegegaegeg"> # SUB-SUB-DIV
            <a class=egaiegeigaegeigaegge", href="link_I_need">Text</a> # First HREF
        <div class="eagegeg"> # SUB-SUB-DIV
            <a class=egaegegaegaeg", href="link_I_need">Text</a> # Second HREF
        <div class="agaeheahrhrahrhr"> # SUB-SUB-DIV
            <a class=arhrharhrahrah", href="link_I_need">Text</a> # Third HREF

    <div class="argagragragaw"> # Second ROW subdiv under the main div
        <div class="aarhrahrah"> # SUB=SUB-DIV
            <a class=arhahrhahr", href="link_I_need">Text</a> # First HREF
        <div class="ahrrahrae"> # SUB-SUB-DIV
            <a class=eagregargreg", href="link_I_need">Text</a> # Second HREF
        <div class="ergrgegaegr"> # SUB-SUB-DIV
            <a class=aegaegregrege", href="link_I_need">Text</a> # Third HREF
        ...
        ...
</div>
```

Using Python Selenium and ChromeDriver I can read the main div `"something"`:

```
main_elem = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[1]")
```

Now, from here I am struggling using correctly Selenium to get all the links under `href` for all the sub-sub-div.

Do you have any idea on how I can easily get those?
Thank you

PS:
I can see that the first sub-sub-div has the following xpath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]
```

Then the second:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]
```

and so on while the second row sub-sub-div `xpath` is:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]
```

so there's `div[2]` rather `div[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the main (parent) element you can get all the child elements containing `href` attribute and get their values, as following:

```py
children = main_elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[href]")
for child in children:
    href = child.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the values of all the *`href`* attributes you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style='something'] div div>a")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@style='something']//div//div/a")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the help. I merged both comments and found the solution for my case as:

```
# read the main DIV with XPATH 
...
# read all the sub-divs
link_elems = element.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/div//div//div/a')
# retrieve the href
for link_elem in link_elems:
    sub_div = link_elem.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//a[starts-with(@href, "/p/")]')
    for sub in sub_div:
        post_href = sub.get_attribute("href")
```